# Does WebView.goback() maintain y scroll view position of previously visited page?

Tags: android, webview

My question is in the title. I'm asking this because I've seen several posts in which people asking how to maintain y scroll position while using goBack(). 
On the other hand, with using goBack, everything seems fine to me - previous position is restored itself. I'm confused. Why is that such a problem? Am I doing something wrong?